# Connect 2 queries in one

Tags: mysql, select, double

Helo, i have problem with mysql! How can i query once to get this two informations in one query?

```
SELECT * FROM PVP_stats 
WHERE UUID = '4c5be598-11e7-480a-a255-483473b2a452' 
LIMIT 1;

SELECT COUNT(id) FROM PVP_stats 
WHERE Elo >= (SELECT Elo FROM PVP_stats 
WHERE UUID = "4c5be598-11e7-480a-a255-483473b2a452");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case to merge the count from second query in first you can use correlated subquery

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM PVP_stats WHERE Elo >= s.Elo ) `count` 
FROM PVP_stats s
WHERE s.UUID = '4c5be598-11e7-480a-a255-483473b2a452'
 LIMIT 1;
```